# Show custom-field selection - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, custom-fields

I added a content rating system to my platform where the authors can select which audience their post is appropriate for. Currently, these options are available:

- Unrated
- G
- PG
- R

The code that I use to display the rating options on the post edit page is:

```
// Article Content Rating
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'rating_select_box' );
function rating_select_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'rating_select_box', // id, used as the html id att
        __( 'Content Rating (optional)' ), // meta box title
        'rating_select_cb', // callback function, spits out the content
        'post', // post type or page. This adds to posts only
        'side', // context, where on the screen
        'low' // priority, where should this go in the context
    );

}

function rating_select_cb( $post ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);
    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last"><span id="timestamp"><label>Article Content Rating: </label>';

    $ratings = array(
        1 => ' G ',
        2 => ' PG ',
        3 => ' R ',
    );

    echo '<select name="rating">';
    echo '<option value=""' . ((($value == '') || !isset($ratings[$value])) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '> Unrated </option>';

    // output each rating as an option
    foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
        echo '<option value="' . $id . '"' . (($value == $id) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '">' . $text. '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

    echo '</span></div>';
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_metadata');

function save_metadata($postid)
{   
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $postid ) ) return false;
    if( empty($postid) ) return false;


    if ( is_null($_REQUEST["rating"]) ) {
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'rating');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($postid, 'rating', $_REQUEST['rating']);
    }

}
// END Article Content Rating
```

Now, the problem is, what code do I add to `single.php` to display their choice? So for instance, if the author selected PG, then I want to `echo 'Content Rating: PG';` or if it was on default (unrated), I want to `echo 'Content Rating: Unrated';`. How is this possible? Ideally, a solution that is light on the server as my platform is heavily trafficked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use the `delete_post_meta()` and `update_post_meta()` functions to remove and modify the custom values. Simply use the [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function to obtain the value for the current post, and echo it out as you see fit.

If you're in [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), it would be something like:

```
$rating = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rating', TRUE);
```

**Edit:**

You already know your ID to rating mapping (I might make this mapping a global array, or some defines, or something similar). Simply use that to look up the string to output:

```
$ratings = array(
    1 => 'G',
    2 => 'PG',
    3 => 'R'
);

if(array_key_exists($rating, $ratings)) {
    echo "Content Rating: $ratings[$rating]";
} else {
    echo "Content Rating: Unrated";
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how I would echo it according to what I want. So for instance, if the author selected PG, then I want to `echo 'Content Rating: PG';` or if it was on default (unrated), I want to `echo 'Content Rating: Unrated';`

Comment: I just tested your edit and it echoes everything as `Content Rating: Unrated`. Do you have a sandbox to test it yourself?

Comment: What is the value of `$rating` in your setup? I'm operating on the assumption that it's the ID of the rating the user chose.

Comment: This is the strange part, when executing `$rating = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rating', TRUE); echo $rating` it echoes the value number correctly. However, your updated code does not function as you proposed. Have you tested it yourself?

Comment: If you get the rating with my first line of code, then use the second line of code (beneath the **Edit** line), you should get what you expect. Validate that `$rating` is what you expect it should be (i.e. echo it out). I have not tested this code, since I don't have a setup like yours. That said, this is a simple thing to do; what I've posted should work.

Comment: Ah, I see what I was doing wrong. I removed the first line when testing your second line (in the edit). Nonetheless, it works fine! Can you please elaborate on how heavy this code? I should not that my platform is heavily trafficked and my server is limited and thus I will need to make any functions as small as possible.

Comment: This kind of lookup is trivial, and should have no giant impact. The `get_post_meta()` call might be an additional round-trip to the database, but I doubt very seriously that you'll notice any problems.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Is it even possible to achieve this with a lighter solution?

Comment: Another option instead of working with ugly globals or redeclaring your arrays is to set up a simple function (something like 'get_ratings_array') in functions.php that returns your static array. Anytime you need to query the key against it, you can make a call to that function. It's up to you on how you want to approach it, I just hate globals and redeclaring things.

Comment: The `get_post_meta()` call will get the rating from the meta cache, so no extra round-trip to the database. WP loads all meta for a post in one hit and caches it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you're saving the key to your custom field rather than its value. I suppose this would be alright if you planned on redeclaring your $ratings array, or (God forbid) use it globally. But still, it would probably be best if you saved the actual Rating rather than its ID number.

So change this line:

```
foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
    echo '<option value="' . $id . '"' . (($value == $id) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '">' . $text. '</option>';
}
```

To this:

```
echo '<option value="Unrated"' . ((!$value || $value == 'Unrated' ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '">Unrated</option>';
foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
    echo '<option value="' .trim($text). '"' . (($value == trim($text)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '">' . $text. '</option>';
}
```

After setting your value within the post, you can add this in single.php:

```
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    echo 'Content Rating: '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);
endwhile;endif;
```

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in my comments, I personally try to avoid globals and redeclaring things as much as possible. So if you would prefer to still reference your ratings by Key, you can get around globals and redeclaring your ratings array by adding a few simple functions:

*functions.php*

```
function gw_get_ratings_array()
{
    $ratings = array(
        1 => 'G',
        2 => 'PG',
        3 => 'R'
    );
    return $ratings;
}
function gw_get_rating($key=0)
{
    $i = (int)$key;
    $ratings = gw_get_ratings_array();
    return isset($ratings[$i]) && $ratings[$i] ? $ratings[$i] : 'Unrated';
}
```

*single.php*

```
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    $rating_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);
    echo 'Content Rating: '.gw_get_rating($rating_id);
endwhile;endif;
```

This way, if you ever need to add more Rating Types, you only need to alter the gw_get_ratings_array function rather than searching for each declaration of the array itself.

Comment: Help me understand your solution. Making these changes, would it mean that each post needs to be updated or are all the previously published posts ratings intact?

Comment: You would either have to update all your posts manually, or run a few SQL queries in your database to turn them from integers to strings.

Comment: Jonah Bishop added a workable solution with my current setup. Would you suggest that your solution to save the rating would be lighter on the server?

Comment: Jonah's solution is perfectly valid. Review my comment, as my own personal coding practice is to avoid globals and redeclaring things as much as possible. But basically, the difference between our solutions in terms of server load is almost negligible.

Comment: @maiorana84 Thank you for the comment. If you have the time, could you kindly demonstrate how you will go about to add a function like `get_ratings_array` within the code that I use? My coding knowledge is limited and thus I do not know how to approach it as you suggest.

Comment: @GaryWoods Updated with an example. It's untested, but it should give you an idea. Either way, if Jonah's solution makes more sense to you, go ahead and use it. Don't sacrifice your code's readability in favor of my own personal preference.